# Merge 2nd line of txt files together

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I have a few hundred txt files with 2 lines each.

To merge them, I would generally do:

```
cat *.txt > final.txt
```

however, I only need to do that for 2nd line of each file so the final output is like

```
2nd line of 1st file
2nd line of 2nd file
2nd line of 3rd file
(and so on..)
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `awk 'NR==2' file` will print the 2nd line of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following with GNU `awk`. `nextfile` is very nice option in GNU `awk` which will skip all lines in current Input_file when a condition is MET.

```
awk 'FNR==2{print;nextfile}' *.txt > output_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you don't have GNU `awk` try. Here since we are assuming there is NO `nextfile` in `awk` so I am creating a `flag` on each file's 2nd line and when it is TRUE simply going next line/skipping them and trying to save sometime. NOTE that this flag value will be RESET on each file's first line too.

```
awk 'FNR==1{flag=""} FNR==2{print;flag=1} flag{next}'  *.txt > output_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Adding `while` and `find` approach too here with `head` and `tail`. AFAIK head and tail shouldn't read whole file.

```
while read line
do
  head -n +2 "$line" | tail -1 
done <  <(find -type f -name "*.txt") > "output_file"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n -s 2p *.txt > final.txt
```

or

```
sed -s '2!d' *.txt > final.txt
```

From `man sed`:

> `-s`: consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.

Comment: `-s`  added to notes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec awk 'NR==2' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`

```
awk 'FNR == 2 { print; nextfile }' *.txt > final.txt
```

`FNR` contains the line number within the current file. When it's on line 2, it will print the line and then go to the next file.

Comment: Hi Barmar sir, since you are an expert of bash would like to request you to please check my 3rd(while+find) answer if that will good in terms of speed etc, kindly provide your views on same.

Comment: It's acceptable, just very verbose and runs lots of processes.

Comment: Thank you for your view, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
 perl -ne ' if($.==2) { print ; close(ARGV) } ' *.txt
```

with sample files

```
$ cat allison1.txt
line1 in file1
line2 in file1

$ cat allison2.txt
line1 in file2
line2 in file2

$ cat allison3.txt
line1 in file3
line2 in file3

$  perl -ne ' if($.==2) { print ; close(ARGV) } ' allison*txt
line2 in file1
line2 in file2
line2 in file3

$
```